# call a class's public method (error: is not a function)

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a class `sessionKotiz` created in file `session.ts`, as follows:

```
export class SessionKotiz{
    designation : string;
    total_in : number;
    total_out: number;

    constructor(){
        total_in = 0;
        total_out = 0;
    }

    reset(){
        total_in = 0;
        total_out = 0;
    }
}
```

Now, in another file (a page actually), I have a member that is of type `SessionKotiz`

```
  export class InfoSessionPage {
  title     : any;
  items     : SessionKotiz = new SessionKotiz();


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
              public events:Events,          public store: StoreAPI,
              private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

    this.items = new SessionKotiz();
  }

  resetSession(){
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Confirm reset',
    message: 'Do you want reset current session?',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'reset',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('reset clicked');
          // Reset report
          this.items.reset();
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

At some point of the code, I want to call method `reset()` of the `SessionKotiz` class, but the error says

```
_this.items.reset is not a function
```

How do I fix this? how to call methods in typescript?

Comment: @NicholasTower Yes, I did, in the constructor of the `infoPage` class

Comment: @NicholasTower I edited the code

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you call `_this.item.reset()`.

Comment: I've deleted my comments and my answer, since the new code is quite a bit different from the old. It also has mismatches in variable names, so it must only be an approximation of what's going on.

Comment: this.items = new SessionKotiz(); _this.item.reset is not a function... somaybe you are missing "s" when calling _this.item.reset

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
export class SessionKotiz{
    designation : string;
    total_in : number;
    total_out: number;

    constructor(){
        this.total_in = 0;
        this.total_out = 0;
    }

    reset(){
        this.total_in = 0;
        this.total_out = 0;
    }
}

resetSession(){
  let self = this;//magic
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Confirm reset',
    message: 'Do you want reset current session?',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'reset',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('reset clicked');
          // Reset report
          self.items.reset();//magic
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  alert.present();
}
```